# Download file from X to Y bytes

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have couple of doubts regarding downloading of file using Java

1. Is it possible to get the size of file before start downloading ?
2. Also is it possible to download only x to y bytes from a file ?

Comment: What is your context? I can see that you have tagged the question with httpurlconnection, so I guess that the file comes from an http server?

Comment: Yeah.. For instance I am trying to download file from www,filehippo.com. How can I achieve this using java?

Answer (score 1):

You can do these provided your server supports these functions. (Its not up to the client)  All NFS and CIFS servers do. Some HTTP and FTP servers do.  How you do this depends on the protocol and the server you are using.

Comment: As I said before I want to download files from web. I am very new to Java so can you please let me know how to achieve this?